# Pan mobile gesture in backbone.js using toe.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, requirejs, gesture

I'm developing a `Cordova` app (using `backbone.js` and `requirejs`) and I'm using `toe.js` js library (https://github.com/dantipa/toe.js) to extends `jQuery` and `backbone.js` events in order to have some mobile gestures like `swipe` and `tap`.
`tap` and `swipe` gestures work great, but I need the `drag` event (`pan` gesture), so I tried to edit the library like this:

```
(function ($, touch, window, undefined) {
    var namespace = 'drag';
    var cfg = {
        distance: 5,
        direction: 'all'
    };
    touch.track(namespace, {
        touchstart: function (event, state, start) {
            state[namespace] = {
                finger: start.point.length
            };
        },
        touchmove: function (event, state, move) {
            // if another finger was used then increment the amount of fingers used
            state[namespace].finger = move.point.length > state[namespace].finger ? move.point.length : state[namespace].finger;
        },
        touchend: function (event, state, end) {
            var opt = $.extend(cfg, event.data),
                duration,
                distance;

            // calc
            duration = touch.calc.getDuration(state.start, end);
            distance = touch.calc.getDistance(state.start.point[0], end.point[0]);

            // check if the swipe was valid
            if (distance > opt.distance) {

                state[namespace].angle = touch.calc.getAngle(state.start.point[0], end.point[0]);
                state[namespace].direction = touch.calc.getDirection(state[namespace].angle);
                state[namespace].distance = distance;

                // fire if the amount of fingers match
                if (opt.direction === 'all' || state[namespace].direction === opt.direction) {
                    $(event.target).trigger($.Event(namespace, touch.addEventParam(state.start, state[namespace])));
                }
            }
        }
    });
}(jQuery, jQuery.toe, this));
```

I'm not sure it's a good way to reproduce `drag` event, so could you help me with that?

I need that event to reproduce the mobile sidebar menu sliding effect:

[image]

How can I do that?
P.s. I tried to replace `toe.js` with `hammer.js` (https://hammerjs.github.io/) that has all gestures events but I had problems in integrating it with `backbone.js` events using `requirejs`.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Hammer.js has a jQuery extension: http://hammerjs.github.io/jquery-plugin/
If you use it instead of the native version, you probably won't have issues integrating with backbone events